# How to prevent unintended flagging of suppressed scope transaction in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm trying to send a simple message, but it seems like it automatically gets flagged as not having a transaction scope ([behavior](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/Pipeline/Outgoing/ForceImmediateDispatchForOperationsInSupressedScopeBehavior.cs)).
The endpoint is running the SQL transport (3.0.1) and NSB 6.1.2, SQL transport runs in default transaction mode (TransactionScope).

As far as I'm aware, no specific action has been taken for this, the only thing I can imagine is that the connection string is shared with Dapper who executed a couple of awaited queries to the database too.

```
var data = await Provider.GetSomeRandomData(message.DataId);
bool synced = false;
await context.Reply(new RandomMessage());
```

If the endpoint is configured using `TransportTransactionMode.SendsAtomicWithReceive` nothing is logged, when `TransportTransactionMode.TransactionScope` is enabled, the logging occurs (and of course presumably also the actual effect is lost).

Ideally, the provider would use (somehow) the same transaction NServiceBus is using, though for querying data it'd need to somehow break out of this transaction context, query the database without breaking the NServiceBus transaction (if this is actually the problem), so that writes would still be transacted.

Comment: This probably is my own ignorance! Could it be that querying data breaks this transaction scope? Preferably I'd have the sends and receives transacted, plus any writes to the database (but not the reads).

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm not sure I understand the issue...

Comment: @SeanFarmar added some example code (very similar) and a description. I'm sure it is me not aligning my transactions 100% correctly, but any help would be much appreciated (the `ideally` part being what the goal would be)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and add `.ConfigureAwait(false)`

`await context.Reply(new RandomMessage())
    .ConfigureAwait(false);`

See [this article for more details](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/reply-to-a-message)

Does that resolve the issue?